# How can I check if the value passed in a PyQt TableModelView is an integer and not for example a letter/symbol?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm relatively new to Python and especially PyQt and model-view programming. I want to have it so that someone can only enter integers in my table and not letters/symbols etc. Here's the model I've made so far for my tableView widget:

```
class PixelTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PixelTableModel, self).__init__()
        self.pixel_coordinate = [[None, None, None, None]]

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 4

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            self.pixel_coordinate[row][column] = value
            print(self.pixel_coordinate) #testing
            return True

        return False


    def data(self, index, role):
       if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
           row = index.row()
           column = index.column()
           value = self.pixel_coordinate[row][column]
           return value



    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role): # section = row column, orientation = vertical/horizontal
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                dict = {0: "Xstart", 1: "Ystart", 2: "Xmax", 3: "Ymax"}
                for key in dict:
                    if section == key:
                        return dict[key]
            else:
                return "Pixel coordinate"
```

It seems to work except obviously for the part where it still can take letters/symbols as input in the tableView. I've tried a couple of things in the setData() method but can't seem to get it work, always get some type of error or it won't even change the box at all. Thanks to anyone that can help me with this. Also sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still interested, after going through it again fixed it with simple try except block:

```
def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
        try:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            string_to_int = int(value)
            self.pixel_coordinate[row][column] = value
            print(self.pixel_coordinate) #testing
            return True

        except ValueError:
            print("Not a number")
            return False

    return False
```